# Mysql ibdata1 size is too big

Tags: mysql

My database size (with indexs): 70GB
My ibdata1 size: 211GB
How can it possible with inno_db_per_file=1 setting?

```
SELECT FILE_NAME,DATA_FREE, (DATA_FREE / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS GB FROM information_schema.files WHERE file_id = 0
```

Result is:
**FILENAME  | DATE_FREE    | GB**
./ibdata1 | 212448837632 | 197

**my settings**

```
innodb_file_per_table=1    
innodb_log_file_size=512M   
innodb_buffer_pool_size=128G  
innodb_buffer_pool_instance=128   
join_buffer_size=64G
```

Comment: I have 518G /var/lib/mysql, and only 25G ibdata1. I guess your db is badly designed and could be greatly optimized

Comment: Also read this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1341 and notice the bug has "Verified" status (i.e. not fixed).

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Possible causes of huge ibdata1:

- It was huge before setting `innodb_file_per_table = 1`
- A huge `UPDATE` or `DELETE` wad run, leading to lots of "undo" data that may have been stored (temporarily) in ibdata1.
- Maybe a very complex `SELECT` needed it for temp space?
- other(?)

Alas, there is no simple way to shrink a big ibdata1.  (There are lots of Q&A about it, probably on this forum.)

Comment: Thank you for comment, i deleted my db and ibdata files with export db.
My new ibdata1 size 9 Gb after import, i will watch this file